# NavHostFragment: Navigation icons at Toolbar not working (ie Menu, NavigationUp icons)

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer, androidx

I am upgrading my app to support tablets. Currently implemented this to my project:

```
implementation "androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.2.0-alpha03"
```

According to docs, to be able to apply dual pane, I need to use NavHostFragment.

However, got issues on my MainActivity's default NavHost.

The icons on my toolbar for navigation are working when I am using the code below

`val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)`

But it started the icons to not working when I use NavHostFragment. See code below.

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(
        R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already got the solution. The problem is on my activity's `onOptionsItemSelected`, it return's `true`.

Fixed when I use `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)`.